# Free sourcecode repository?

Tags: java, android, repository

is there a free sourcecode repository for private sourcecode?

I am looking for a sourcecode repository where I can upload my Android/Java projects with Eclipse. The sourcecode should not be visible to others. I have only found solutions like sourceforge which provide an open-source repository.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/

Comment: You could just create a local git server, or bitbucket, it's just as good I think.

Comment: Thank you. Bitbucket is the best solution. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/ offer free private Git and Mercurial repositories. The downside is it only allow up to 7 other persons (for ALL of your repositories) to access your code at a given time.

Also https://github.com/ offer free public repositories wich are visibles to anyone but they could be put under the license of your choice (so your code is visible but can't legally be copied and redistributed).

Given it's size, chances your project is even seen by anyone you don't give the url are near to zero, and you have a legal way to prove you own the code posted on.